# Регулярные выражения для поиска по файлу с заменой

Tags: .net, регулярные-выражения, powershell

Вот PowerShell скрипт по замене connectionString

```powershell
param ([string]$path, [string]$value)
$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($path)
$pattern = '(?<=<target[\n\n\n]*connectionString=\")(.*)(?=\"[\n\r\s]*>)'
$regex = New-Object Text.RegularExpressions.Regex $pattern
$text = $regex.Replace($text, $value)
[IO.File]::WriteAllText($path, $text)
```

Нужно поправить шаблон в скрипте, чтобы скрипт находил строку подключения и делал замену.
Пример файла в котором будет искать:

```xml
   <target name="database"  type="AsyncWrapper" batchSize="10" overflowAction="Block">
            <target name="database"
                    xsi:type="Database"
                    dbProvider="System.Data.OracleClient"
                    connectionString="Подключение"
                    keepConnection="true"
                    commandText="Запрос">
```

Comment: а что не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно следующего паттерна:

```powershell
$pattern = '(?<=connectionString=").*?(?=")'
```

Экранировать двойные кавычки не нужно.

---

Чтобы сматчить значение более точно, а именно внутри тега `target`, нужно добавить опцию `[RegexOptions]::Singleline` в сам объект регекса:

```powershell
$pattern = '(?<=<target .*?connectionString=").*?(?=")'
$regex = New-Object Text.RegularExpressions.Regex $pattern, singleline
```

---

А вообще, я бы использовал xml-парсер для разбора и изменения конфига.

Comment: Спасибо. Поздно я увидел, ваш комментарий, вот мой вариант, может кому пригодится '(?<=<target[\n\r\s\w\W]*connectionString=\")(.*)(?=\")'